# How to wrap up a function and its parameters... sort of a "super delegate"?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a chunk of code that does a "file put" operation inside a moderately complicated piece of retry and try/catch logic. This is working fine, it looks roughly like this:

```
while (...) {
try {
    FilePut(source, destination)
    }
catch () {
   //Check exception type, possibly re-throw, possibly return, possibly increment
   //counters being checked by while loop
   }
}
```

The details of this logic aren't the issue. But I'm realizing I have several other operations that also need to execute inside this same kind of logic and I want to avoid copy and pasting this logic around my application. I'd like to move it to a function and reuse that function. That function would have to take some sort of reference to the operation to be called, and the try logic would execute that operation (file put, file get, whatever).

This seems like a great place for a delegate, but the problem is, each of these operations has a different signature, so I'm not sure how to be able to write my above logic to be able to call "any" operation.

Is there a good way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an [`Action` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) to hide all of the different signatures. Something like this:

```
public void DoAction(Action action)
{
    // Make the boilerplate code whatever you need it to be. 
    // I've just used a try catch for simplicity.
    try
    {
        // Call the action at the appropriate time.
        action();
    }
    catch
    {
        // Handle any exceptions as you wish.
    }
}
```

Then, to be able to handle actions with different signatures, you can define a few overloads that take different types of the generic `Action<T>` delegates and all of the necessary arguments. These overloads will "curry" the generic action and its arguments to a plain `Action`:

```
public void DoAction<T>(Action<T> action, T arg1)
{
    DoAction(() => action(arg1));
}

public void DoAction<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
{
    DoAction(() => action(arg1, arg2));
}

public void DoAction<T1, T2, T3>(Action<T1, T2, T3> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
{
    DoAction(() => action(arg1, arg2, arg3));
}

// etc...
```

To use:

```
public void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    DoAction(MethodThatTakesTwoInts, 42, 23);
    DoAction(MethodThatTakesAString, "Don't Panic!");
}
```

Also, if you not familiar with them, take a look at the related family of [`Func` delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960) as well for good measure.

Comment: how will this satisfy the fact that each of the operations has a different signature?

Comment: @desigeek DoAction(()=>FilePut(source, dest)); DoAction(() => bla-bla1(x)); DoAction(() => bla-bla3(x1, x2, x3));

Comment: The signature differences are hidden inside the `Action` delegate. The `Action` delegates all have the same signature.

Comment: I amended my answer to be a little more clear about currying various signatures down to an `Action` delegate.

Comment: Okay, your idea seems to work (thanks) although I'm not yet trying the third block of code you show above. Frankly, I'm a bit dumbfounded here. Why does this work? If one can pass "anything" to Action<> in c#, why do we have Action<...> with all its various overloads? Up till now I was thinking that whenever I saw Action<x,y> for example, it would only "work" when dealing with a method taking two of the right type of parameters.. but this is obviously not the "end of the story". What am I missing?

Comment: I think what your missing is the fact that the overloads are generic methods. Yes, it's true that an `Action<int, string>` must take an `int` and a `string`, but a generic method will take whatever the type constraint allows (in this case, anything). The concrete types will be inferred at each instance where you use the generic methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
protected void TryNTimes(int numberOfTries, Action action)
{
    try
    {
        if (numberOfTries == 0) return;
        action();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        TryNTimes(numberOfTries - 1, action);
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
TryNTimes(10, () => Foo());
```

Comment: Very clean code, but it eats your exceptions. How do you know if action succeeded or not? Better put the if statement in the catch block, recurse if enough tries left and rethrow otherwise.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten: You're right. I just considered "exception => try again" logic, as an start point to OP.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: It was just the first thing that came into my mind.